# How to bind MySQL data to dynamically created Form Elements

Tags: php

I have some sets of form elements created dynamically which I use on page creation.

```
<?php for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){ ?>
<div id="hold">
    <input type="text" name="slinks<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $slinks[$i]; ?>" placeholder="Input Link Name" />
    <select name="cat<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Category</option>
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I am able to insert the values into my MySQL database. I want to populate values into these fields on page edit. **My problem is how to bind values into the form elements** assuming my database fetched sample values as:

```
<?php
    $query = $dhb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE $col = ?");
    $query->execute(array($id));
    $amt = $query->rowCount();
    $rows = $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    while($z = $query->fetch()){
        print_r($z);
    }
?>
```

And the output from print_r()

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => Item3
)
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Item1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Item2
)
```

Comment: tell me how do u wanna you result . my mean value and name in option of a single select. b/c ur question suggest that it is making 6 select box. and you php result seem to assign result in options of a select.so clear it first.

Comment: I want to to bind the outputs from the database to the form elements. If only 3 of the 6 generated divs have inputs then they get filled but the remaining 3 left blank in case a new field is to be added as an update.

Comment: Is it really `[1] => 1 [2] => Item1` for the 2nd array or it's suppose to be `[0] => 1 [1] => Item1` ?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Yes. The textbox value is 1 while the select option value is 2 for the first array generated. So is the 2nd and 3rd. I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: tell me if you have any variable, or how do you identify that it is in edit mode.then i will write my answer.

Comment: From my posted MySQL query $col = ? stands for the id of the created form ID. So on update, it gets the form ID from the database then appends the values to the form elements.

Answer (score 1):

lets assume $edit=true, means it is in edit mode. then you php code will be..
assuming you have ever set different

```
<?php
$query = $dhb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE $col = ?");
$query->execute(array($id));
$index = array();
$value = array();
$amt = $query->rowCount();
$rows = $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
while($z = $query->fetch()){
    print_r($z);
$index[] = $z[0];
$value[$z[0]] = $z[1];

}
?>
```

and you html code will be...

```
<?php  if($edit && is_array($index) && is_array($value)){
           $flagForNewField = false;
           for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){ 
               if(in_array($i,$index){ ?>    
                <div id="hold">
                <input type="text" name="slinks<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $slinks[$i]; ?>" placeholder="Input Link Name" />
                <select name="cat<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Category</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="<?php if($i==1){echo "selected";}else{} ?>">Item 1</option>
                    <option value="<?php if($i==2){echo "selected";}else{} ?>">Item 2</option>
                    <option value="<?php if($i==3){echo "selected";}else{} ?>">Item 3</option>
                </select>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }else{
                $flagForNewField = true;
                // ccase if input in not in fetched result
                }
            } 
        }else{
            for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++){ ?>

            <div id="hold">
            <input type="text" name="slinks<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $slinks[$i]; ?>" placeholder="Input Link Name" />
            <select name="cat<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Category</option>
                <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                <option value="2">Item 2</option>
                <option value="3">Item 3</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
    <?php }
    }?>
```

Comment: I'll implement and get back to you asap. Thanks for the lead anyways.

Comment: Welcome always. hope so it is, what you need.

Comment: I have some issues. The loop isn't working as expected. If 6 rows were inserted, on edit, it multiplies the 6 initial rows by the 6 fetched rows making it 36 rows returned. How do I get to fix the loop issue?

Comment: but here is single lopp how it can become 36 rows, it means you are doing , loop under loop. that might be wrong place your code, then i will check

Comment: Please do check. Thanks in anticipation for your feedback.

Comment: can you tell me what is your current code. b/c whatever i suggested , it can't produce 36 rows.

Comment: Just exactly what you gave is what I have here.

Comment: are you putting html code inside php code. my mean html code inside while loop , fetched from db.

Comment: Thanks. I got it settled later on using some tweaks from your code. Thanks for the lead